# Some PDF files downloaded using php are truncated

Tags: php, function, file, pdf

I'm trying to write a php function that will save locally several PDF files, some are downloaded just fine, but others appear to be truncated and could not be opned with a PDF reader.

The actual save function is called by a function that locates the paths:

```
   function findURLs(){

      // do something to find URLs & next print them

      while(*some condition*){
         savePDF($url,$id);
      }    
    }
```

This is the actual function:

```
  function savePDF($url,$id){

    $path="../downloads/".$id.".pdf";

    try {
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        $handle = fopen($path, "w");
        fwrite($handle, $data);
        fclose($handle);
        return true;
        echo "file saved";  
      } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Any suggestions? could it be the remote file size?

Thanks!

> *p.s. I wish to save the files to the server (my localhost) not download the files via the browser..

Comment: What happens if you access the URLs to the PDFs that doesn't work directly in your browser? Do they work then?

Comment: `fwrite()` returns the number of bytes written, you can compare this to `strlen($data)` to verify that you've written everything you've downloaded.

Comment: The URLs open just fine in a browser

Comment: curl() has a lot more options for both debugging, and making sure things work, i would consider switching to that

Comment: I've tried using curl and still encounter the same issues, some PDFs are truncated..